# How to display django models with datetime field in chart using chartjs?

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I have a django model which is called ScanBatch. Scan batch is made up of fields like the timestamp (datetime field), domain (char field) and total ids found (integer field).

My chart code is :

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, { 
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: []
        },
        
        options: {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                id: 'A',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
              }, {
                id: 'B',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'right',
                ticks: {
                  max: 1,
                  min: 0
                }
              }]
            }
          }
    });
```

models code is

```
class ScanBatch(models.Model):
   domain = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   valid_ids_found = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How do I make the chart show the batch data historically from django and then output it to the chart?

I want to show the batches historically by date and also group by domain.

example of what the data to plot is like are :

> [www.someexample.com](http://www.someexample.com) | 2022-09-03 | 34
>
> [www.someexample.com](http://www.someexample.com) | 2022-09-04 | 55

Comment: Where do you want to display the date, on an axis?

Comment: @SamuelKazeem just want data plotted historically (by date) and grouped by domain (meaning the total valid IDs found for like 5 domains which are the same plotted)

Comment: and yes on the x axis i wanna give the date

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the timestamps as date, together with the domain. Then you will need to sum up all the ID's right? (For each day)

To do that, you can get it from:

### Added domain

##### Edit start

```
chartdata = ScanBatch.objects.all().values('timestamp__date','domain').annotate(models.Sum('valid_ids_found'))
```

Then pass that onto the template.

In the template, to prep the data you need to iterate over it in javascript.
Like so:

```
const chartData = {{ chart_data |safe }};
let arr = [];
let arrlabels = [];
let domainlabels = [];
for (let value of Object.values(chartData)) {
  arr.push(value.valid_ids_found__sum); 
  arrlabels.push(value.timestamp__date); 
  domainlabels.push(value.domain)
}
console.log(chartData)
```

##### Edit end

Now you have your chart data prepped, ready to use in the chart.

```
const chartData = {{ chart_data |safe }};
let arr = []
let arrlabels = []
for (let value of Object.values(chartData)) {
  arr.push(value.valid_ids_found__sum); 
  arrlabels.push(value.timestamp__date); 
}
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, { 
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: arrlabels ,
            datasets: arr
        },
        
        options: {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                id: 'A',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
              }, {
                id: 'B',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'right',
                ticks: {
                  max: 1,
                  min: 0
                }
              }]
            }
          }
    });
```

This is the first part at least, I do not have enough knowledge of Chart.js to differentiate between domain also. Sorry bud. Might help you along though!

Comment: I also need to group by domain as there are multiple domains with same name

Comment: I added an extra query, this should output the domain together with the data. I did not edit the chart-javascript.

Comment: Please, use the new query I provided. The one where it annotates the domain is not good. Domain needs to be in values. My bad, sorry. @allenE